# I want delete selected record from database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a problem. I want to delete row from mysql table. I don't understand what is wrong. Application return error only production linux enviroment, on Windows everything is okay.

```
def sql_execute(conn, sql, val):
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        conn.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("sql_insert: ", info.error_insert_info, e)
    
def delete_type_for_id(conn, val):
    sql = "DELETE FROM types WHERE id = '{}'".format(val)
    db.sql_execute(conn, sql, val)

task_man.delete_task_for_id(conn, "3155")
```

Flask app is quite big so i can't paste all code, but probably bug is here.

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    task_man.delete_task_for_id(conn, "3155")
  File "/home/Dianetello/controllers/tasks_controller.py", line 41, in delete_task_for_id
    db.sql_execute(conn, sql, val)
  File "/home/Dianetello/utils/db_manager/mysql_connector.py", line 50, in sql_execute
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
  File "/home/Dianetello/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 257, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/home/Dianetello/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 651, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

- **mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))**
- **mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.17-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)**

Comment: ```sql = "DELETE FROM types WHERE id = %s",(val)```

Comment: I found solution :) I think that is not really pretty code, but working. On future I will write better data handle layer:
`code
def delete_task_for_id(conn, val):
    sql = "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = '{}'".format(val)
    db.sql_drop(conn, sql)

def sql_drop(conn, sql):
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, multi=True)
        conn.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("sql_drop: ", info.error_drop_info, e)
`
Maybe to use one method for all statement?

Comment: Use parameter substitution, not string formatting, to set values in the query.  `cursor.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE tasks WHERE id = %s', (val,))`.